# Date and Time merging to datetimefield

Tags: django

```
views.py 

def KEBReading1(request):


q2=KEBReading.objects.all().order_by('datetime_reading')[:30]

form = KEBReading_form()
monthform=MonthForm()
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.POST.get('KEBsubmit'):
        form = KEBReading_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                prevdate=KEBReading.objects.latest("datetime_reading")    

                print "teena"             

                date=form.cleaned_data["Date"]
                print date
                time=form.cleaned_data["Time"]
                print time
                kr_truepower_reading = form.cleaned_data["truepower_reading"]
                kr_apparentpower_reading = form.cleaned_data["apparentpower_reading"]

                truepower_consumed1=kr_truepower_reading-prevdate.truepower_reading
                powerfactor1=((kr_truepower_reading-prevdate.truepower_reading)/(kr_apparentpower_reading-prevdate.apparentpower_reading))     
                form1=form.save(commit=False)
                form1.datetime_reading__date=date


                form1.datetime_reading___time=time
                print type(date)

                form1.truepower_consumed=truepower_consumed1
                form1.powerfactor=powerfactor1

                print form1.powerfactor


                form1.save()
```

how do i merge the date field and time field value i retrieved into a datetime field to store it the database. i have a filed called datetime_reading. and in my page i enter date and time field separately. how do i merge the date and time field into a single datetime field to store it in datetime_reading column in DB

Comment: The answers below should work, the problem is you've defined `datetime=models.DateTimeField()` which overwrites the `import datetime`. Name the `models.DateTimeField()` with a different variable, or use `import datetime as your_datetime` with the naming of your choice.

Answer (score 15):

To merge date and time you need to use [`datetime.combine`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine)

```
datetime.combine(date, time)
```

Comment: it gives error saying
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'combine'. i gave as form1.datetime.combine(date,time)

Comment: I think you should use:
datetime_reading = datetime.datetime.combine( date, time )

Comment: For people coming here looking for a Django solution, you may or may not have to make the resulting `datetime` timezone-aware (depending whether your `USE_TZ` is `True` or `False`).

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
 form1.datetime_reading = datetime.combine(date, time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using first strftime in your time like this:

```
utime = strftime.time("......")
```

Then:

```
datetime.datetime.combine(date, utime)
```

Comment: i gave it. but its not workin. throwing same error "NoneType object has no attribute called combine". i gave it has   date=form.cleaned_data["Date"]
 time=form.cleaned_data["Time"]
 utime =time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")   d=form1.datetime.datetime.combine(date,utime)

Comment: datetime=models.DateTimeField()
   
    truepower_reading=models.DecimalField(verbose_name="True Power Reading(KWH)",max_digits=6,decimal_places=2,blank=False,null=False)
 apparentpower_reading=models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Apparent Power Reading(KVAH)",max_digits=6,decimal_places=2,blank=False,null=False)
    truepower_consumed=models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2,blank=False,null=False)
    voltage_reading=models.IntegerField(blank=False,null=False)
    powerfactor=models.DecimalField(max_digits=3,decimal_places=2)

Comment: Don't put it here, it's hard to read... Just update your question and put it there